# Print the data obtained from " ajax " in the jwplayer javascript

Tags: jquery

I want to print the data obtained from " ajax " in the jwplayer javascript . Help me , I'm newbie on javascript . Please help me! Sorry for my poor English .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/a/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="key";</script>
<div id="my-video">Loading ...</div>
<script>
    function loadPlayer(link){  
        var data = 'zing=' + link;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/a/zing.php",
            data: data,
            success: function (getlink){jwplayer("my-video").setup({
                getlink, 
                image: "http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/Wf8BfcSt-640.jpg",
                width: "580",
                height: "370",
                primary: "html5",
                advertising: { 
                    client: "vast",
                    schedule: {"myAds":{"offset":"15","tag":"http://www.adotube.com/php/services/player/OMLService.php?avpid=oRYYzvQ&platform_version=vast20&ad_type=linear&groupbypass=1&HTTP_REFERER=http://www.longtailvideo.com&video_identifier=longtailvideo.com,test"}}
                }
            });}  
        });    
    }
</script>
<script>loadPlayer('http://tv.zing.vn/video/Date-a-Live-II-Tap-10-END/IWZA7BIW.html');</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem is in the object you are passing to the `init` of the `jwPlayer.setup`:

```
success: function (getlink){
  jwplayer("my-video").setup({
    getlink, // This is wrong. There must be some name of the parameter.
```

May be, this is what you are looking for?

```
success: function (getlink){
  jwplayer("my-video").setup({
    url: getlink, // Use the name of the parameter here?
```

Comment: Sources is it. Okay, what does `getlink` contain?

Comment: function (getlink){//here

Comment: @HoàngXanh You don't understand. What's the content of `getlink`?

Comment: sorry :v 
[{file: "http://stream7.tv.zdn.vn/streaming/2892de007c1c39f79c2eee9bfe99d9fb/566abeb2/Video720/2014/0626/5e/1fca0d061489d58a3af74ced9f85259f.mp4",type:"mp4",label: "720p"},
     {file: "http://stream7.tv.zdn.vn/streaming/b807a2e993a36c308f80146807e20531/566abeb2/Video480/2014/0626/5e/7afb2637752002454cc5ec06f6ffa10a.mp4",type:"mp4",label: "480p"},
     {file: "http://stream.m.tv.zdn.vn/tv/0980ba6aebba428982d471a6375667d9/566abeb2/Video3GP/2014/0626/5e/eacad93448d77437cf7b763e57f22768.3gp",type:"mp4",label: "360p","default": "true"}]

Comment: That was a mistake :v jwplayer 7 are different. Tks for your help